# Applying Rouché's theorem to $z^4 -20z^2 - 2z + 24$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find zeroes of polynomial $z^4 - 20z^2 - 2z + 24$ in set $1 < |z| < 3$. To do so I'm going to apply Rouché's theorem.

**My work so far**

For $|z| = 1$

$$|z^4 - 20z^2 - 2z| \le |z^4| + 20|z^2| + 2|z| = 1 + 20 + 2 = 23 < 24$$

So on disk $|z| < 1$ function $z^4 - 20z^2 - 2z + 24$ has the same number of zeroes as function $24$ which means that it has no roots.

For $|z| = 3$

$$|z^4 - 2z + 24| \le |z^4| + 2|z| + 24 = 3^4 + 2 \cdot 3 + 24 = 111 < 180 = 20|z^2|$$

So on disk $|z| < 3$ function $z^4 - 20z^2 - 2z + 24$ has the same number of zeroes as function $20z^2$ which means that it has two roots.

Finally on disk $1 < |z| < 3$ we have two roots ($2 - 0 = 0$).

Is my justification correct?

Comment: That is correct. What are your doubts about the solution?

Comment: The only confusion part is the title. $|z^4 - 2z + 24|$ is not a polynomial, and $z^4 - 2z + 24$ is not the polynomial you are investigating.

Comment: I have none doubts. I'm new to complex analysis and I was just wondering if I understand  that theorem correctly ;))